# "Precision-moving" a body using Phaser and p2.js physics

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to move a dynamic body from point A to point B using Phaser 2.4.6 and the p2.js version included with it. It is really important that the body accurately stops at the destination point and not behind the point or after it passed it (very low tolerances are acceptable). I have tried two approaches so far, and failed with both:

- Use a Phaser tween to change the coordinates of the body throughout the route that I want it to move on. This works beautifully, except the body can skip over static bodies.

[image: Using a Phaser tween]

Sample code:

```
game.add.tween(sprite.body).to(
    { x: destinationX, y: destinationY },
    timeInterval,
    Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.InOut,
    true
);
```

- Use the p2 `force` property to move the body on the desired path. The collisions with other bodies work well this time, but it is almost impossible to make the body stop at exactly the coordinates I want it to. I tried to decrease the force applied as the body approaches the destination, which works perfect in 90% of the cases. However, in low-performance scenarios the animation is "jittery" (which is to be expected) but also fails to hit the target point and goes over it, sometimes by a lot. I would even accept the option to forcefully stop the body when it hits the destination and hurt the realism of the scene a little bit, but I was unable to do that (tried to set both force and velocity to 0, damping to 1, etc. - nothing worked).

Below some sample code (in the Phaser engine `sprite.body.data` is pointing to the p2.js physics body):

```
// OUTSIDE OF THE GAME LOOP:
var magnitude = game.physics.p2.pxmi(-speed);
var angle = entity.body.data.angle + Math.PI / 2;
var forceX = (magnitude * Math.cos(angle)) / 10;
var forceY = (magnitude * Math.sin(angle)) / 10;

// IN THE GAME LOOP:
sprite.body.data.force[0] = forceX;
sprite.body.data.force[1] = forceY;
// Decrease forceX and forceY as the body approaches the destination
```

Can anybody please provide some suggestions? I am lost at this point, so I could even use an educated guess from someone familiar with some other physics engine.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the code for what you've tried so we have a starting point to help?

Comment: @JamesSkemp I added some code. I would really like to get the second approach to work. Currently I am decreasing the force on the X and Y axes as the sprite is approaching the destination, until eventually they are both zero. This works, but if the CPU is very busy the sprite starts moving jittery (which is to be expected) and eventually goes beyond the destination point.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played with physics extensively, but from what I've seen, moving a physics-enabled body is usually done via `body.velocity`.

See a quick example I put together: http://phaser.io/sandbox/wUGlsnRx

Comment: I just tried using `velocity`, but I get the same results as using the `force` property, which is the sprite ends up going beyond the destination point in scenarios where the CPU is very busy. It seems impossible to have the sprite accurately and consistently stop at the destination point. I'm thinking to maybe start looking at using a distance constraint, but I was hoping to find a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Kamen Minkov is right. If you want to use Physics then you can't be tweening your bodies or manually changing the position. You mention it has trouble under high load though, could this be an issue with P2 performance? [Here's something similar for 3D games](https://www.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/32buec/why_do_games_still_have_so_much_trouble_with/). Is Arcade physics an option for your 2D game?

> this method is extremely poor on performance, because your collider is composed of a whole lot of vertices that it constantly needs to update every frame, and it's much more computationally expensive to see if something collided with it because of its odd shape. It's much, much, much quicker to use a "capsule" collider for a human character, which is just a cylinder with rounded tops, that is roughly the size of your character. It's much easier on memory, and it's much quicker to calculate a collision on such a simple shape.

Don't you also [need a special outlining for P2 physics?](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor/tutorials/phaser-p2-physics-example-tutorial) Perhaps there's an issue with that. Check out your image in [Physics Editor](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor).

Check out the P2 [example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/p2-physics/collide-custom-bounds) to make sure your setting it up correctly.